# How can I solve the Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `spy`, that is appearing in the console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, react-props, smooth-scrolling

I have seen some similar problems some of which have been answered, but I feel props my specific case might need a different treatment. So I have the following React code:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../deuxLogo.png";
import { Link as LinkS } from "react-scroll";

function LoginHeader() {
  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <LinkS
        to="signupForm"
        spy={true}
        smooth={true}
        offset={-70}
        duration={500}
        className="App-link"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        Click here or scroll down, to Signup!
      </LinkS>
    </header>
  );
}

export default LoginHeader;
```

My problem is am having the above captioned Warning on both `spy` and `smooth`. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have to use only name of  props without true.

```
  <LinkS
    to="signupForm"
    spy
    smooth
    offset={-70}
    duration={500}
    className="App-link"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
  >
    Click here or scroll down, to Signup!
  </LinkS>
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @Сергей Петрашко, but that did not help as it is sending the same boolean value `true` to the DOM. So, am still getting the same warning.